# R fails to retrieve all combinations

Tags: r

R fails to retrieve all the combinations from a `for` loop.

Run the following code:

```
x1 <-5
x2 <-13
x3 <- 33
alpha_df <- NULL
alpha_df <- as.data.frame(alpha_df)
alpha_df[1:1000,] <- NA
alpha_df[,1:4] <- NA
count <-0
for(i in c(0:10)/10){
  for(j in c(0:10)/10){
    for(k in c(0:10)/10){
      if(i+j+k == 1){
        count <-count +1
        alpha_df[count,1] <- i
        alpha_df[count,2] <- j
        alpha_df[count,3] <- k
        alpha_df[count,4] = i*x1 + j* x2 +k*x3
      }
    }
  }
}
alpha_df <- na.omit(alpha_df)
View(alpha_df)
```

It fails to retrieve the output like (0.7,0.2,0.1), similar outputs in (0.6,,) and so on.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19344770/3710546) to avoid `for` loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this :

```
if(all.equal(i+j+k,1) == T)
```

instead of

```
if(i+j+k == 1)
```

You can reed [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) which will explains why R doesn't think some numbers are equal (it is a rounding problem), and `all.equal` uses a tolerance so that 0.7+0.2+0.1 = 1

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19344770/3710546) to avoid `for` loops.

```
x1 <-5
x2 <-13
x3 <- 33
alpha_df <- expand.grid(replicate(3, list(0:10/10)))
alpha_df <- alpha_df[abs(rowSums(alpha_df)-1) < .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5,]
within(alpha_df, Var4 <- Var1*x1 + Var2*x2 + Var3*x3)
```

Comment: Nice solution. I'd define `alpha_df<-expand.grid(replicate(3,list(0:10/10)))`, just to generalize when you want to create more than 3 columns.

Comment: @nicola Nice improvement. May I?

Comment: Looks very complicated

Comment: @bramtayl  primary school playground?

Comment: People who live in glass houses shouldn't throw stones.

Comment: @bramtayl  Could you stop to act as kid now?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dplyr answer without loops:

```
i = data_frame(i = c(0:10)/10)

all.equal = Vectorize(all.equal)

result = 
  i %>%
  merge(i %>% rename(j = i)) %>%
  merge(i %>% rename(k = i)) %>%
  filter(1 %>% all.equal(i+j+k) %>% `==`("TRUE")) %>%
  mutate(l = i*x1 + j*x2 + k*x3)
```

Comment: Looks very complicated.

Comment: dplyr doesn't have cross_joins implemented yet